# Explicit examples of alternating multilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra

I think explicit examples of multilinear forms would help me understand them. (I'm studying determinants.) I know they are helpful (only?) for calculating volumes, which is why any alternating multilinear form $w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ vanishes if the arguments are linearly dependent. Also, because they are associated with volumes, it makes sense that switching the arguments will switch the sign.

What would an alternating multilinear form $w(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ look like in terms of the components of each vector $x_j = (\xi_{j1},\ldots,\xi_{jn})$ ?

Comment: In retrospect the question is kind of vague, but I think the following would've helped me:

An alternating form can be constructed by the antisymmetrization of a general multilinear form. And a general multilinear form 
$$f(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$$
can be constructed as the product of $n$ linear functionals $f_1,\ldots, f_n$ as follows $$f(v_1, \ldots, v_n) = f_1(v_1)\cdots f_n(v_n).$$

The antisymmetrization of the above gives a multilinear form (equal up to a constant to $\det (f_i(v_j))$). For instance $\omega(v_1, v_2) = f_1(v_1)f_2(v_2)-f_2(v_1)f_1(v_2)$ fits the bill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be an alternating two form. We can define $\omega$ by specifying its action on a standard basis.

---

$$ \omega(e_1,e_1) = \omega_{11} = 0 $$
$$ \omega(e_2,e_2) = \omega_{22} = 0 $$
$$ \omega(e_1,e_2) = \omega_{12} $$
$$ \omega(e_2,e_1) = \omega_{21}  = - \omega_{12}$$

---

Now let omega act on  vectors $v = v^1 e_1 + v^2 e_2$ and $w = w^1 e_1 + w^2 e_2$ (note the superscripts here are not powers just labels).

$$ \omega(v,w ) = \omega( v^1 e_1 + v^2 e_2, w^1 e_1 + w^2 e_2 ) $$

$$= v^1 w^1 \omega(e_1,e_1) + v^1 w^2 \omega(e_1,e_2) + v^2 w^1 \omega(e_2,e_1) + v^2 w^2 \omega(e_2,e_2)$$

$$= 0 +  v^1 w^2 \omega(e_1,e_2) + v^2 w^1 \omega(e_2,e_1) + 0$$

$$=v^1 w^2 \omega_{12} + v^2 w^1 \omega_{21}$$

$$=(v^1 w^2  - v^2 w^1) \omega_{12}$$

---

As you can see the action of the bilinear form can be completely described in terms of its components and the components of the vectors it is acting on. In more classical treatments in tensors you will often encounter expressions like $``$ The tensor $\omega_{ij}$ ". In physics this is still the notation we use today.

---

We can see that in general that the components of an alternating form  $\omega_{i_1 i_2 i_3\dots i_n}$ will be zero if any pair of subscripts are the same and antisymmetric under the exchange of any pair of indices.

Now consider what will happen if we feed this form two vectors which are the same.

$$ \omega( \xi, \xi, \eta, \dots, \zeta ) = \sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots i_n} \omega_{i_1 i_2 i_3 \dots i_n } \xi^{i_1} \xi^{i_2} \eta^{i_3} \cdots \zeta^{i_n} $$

Now we exchange $i_1$ and $i_2$ in $\omega$, picking up a negative sign, and commute the numbers $\xi^1$ and $\xi^2$.

$$= -\sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots i_n} \omega_{i_2 i_1 i_3 \dots i_n } \xi^{i_2} \xi^{i_1} \eta^{i_3} \cdots \zeta^{i_n} $$

$$ = - \omega(\xi, \xi, \eta, \dots , \zeta)$$

So we have that the number $\omega(\xi,\xi,\eta,\dots,\zeta)$ is its own negative. The only way this is possible is if $\omega(\xi,\xi,\eta,\dots,\zeta)=0$.

---

As an example of a "useful" alternating bilinear form, in Electrodynamics the Electromagnetic Field Tensor $F_{\mu \nu}$ is alternating.

Comment: Thanks, that helped my confusion. I'd like to make my question a bit more specific. 

In the book I'm studying, there are some kinda concrete examples of linear functionals (each linear functional $y(x)$ is of the form $y(x) = \alpha_1  \xi_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n \xi_n$ for $ x = (\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)$) and bilinear forms (for instance a bilinear form $w(x,y) = u(x)v(y)$ where $u$ and $v$ are any linear functionals). 

Are there any similar examples that'll help me understand alternating multilinear forms? If I see them, I may be better able to see why they vanish when two arguments are equal.

Comment: Or should I be content with understanding alternating multilinear forms just by understanding their action on a basis?

Comment: What you have written implicitly uses the action of these forms on a basis. For instance $\alpha_1 = y(e_1)$. Notice also that $\omega$ I wrote down is completely generic in two dimensions with $\omega_{12}$ playing the role of the $\alpha$'s.

Comment: I'll try and think of another example and add it if I have time later.

Comment: I added a more general expression for the components of alternating forms and demonstrated why we get zero if we feed it a pair of identical vectors. You may be interested in looking up the wedge product which is a way of combining alternating forms to get a new alternating form.